# After install and start Solr server I get error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I install gem 'sunspot_rails' 'sunspot_solr'. I start Solr server by bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start. I get this error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: That's the end exception - the log up to that point is what'll tell you what the actual error is.